# Window exe API cors issue when calling from any webapp. C++

Tags: javascript, c++, ajax, cors

We've created one EXE file using the CPP language and create one API like `http://localhost:5800/get-id/`. when I open in browser return me the perfect output.

When I used `fetch` in HTML > script page, then getting `No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is present on the requested resource.`

Code1:

```
fetch("http://localhost:5800/get-id/", {method: 'GET').then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.text()); 
}).catch(function(error) {  
  console.log('Request failed', error)  
});
```

After research, I've added the `mode: no-cors` error lost but getting an empty response.
Code2:

```
fetch("http://localhost:5800/get-id/", {method: 'GET', mode: 'no-cors'}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.text()); 
}).catch(function(error) {  
  console.log('Request failed', error)  
});
```

If I use `code2` in any inspect console then getting an empty body but when I open `http://localhost:5800/get-id/` in the browser and try to hit `code2` in the console then getting the perfect parameter.

It means, localhost domain it's working fine but when it's fetched from any domain through my error.

What is the proper solution for it? In C/CPP language how can we allow cors?

Strange:

when I hit from console, it's show me empty
[image]

For same request I checked network tab, show 200 OK with proper response / preview data
[image]

Comment: Firstly, there is no language called "C, CPP".  Which are you using?  C or C++?  These languages are different.  Secondly, the error message implies that there is a header which your program is supposed to output, but it is not outputting.  Are you familiar with how server-side applications are expected to behave when serving content?  If you wish to continue having this question tagged as either C or C++, I suggest you show the relevant code.

Comment: Can you use the same port for both `/getdata` and `/get-id/`, something like `http://localhost:5800/getdata`? The issue will go away as it only relates to web page from one domain (localhost:4563 in your case) calling another domain (localhost:5800).

Comment: @paddy C++ language exe build.

Comment: @Vitalii both are same port, by mistaken I put 4563. Can you check another two snapshot I've attached.

Comment: @GunjanPatel if the page is on the same domain as request try removing `http://localhost:5800`, e.i. `fetch("/get-id/", ....)`

Comment: @Vitalii For same domain it's working but assume, service running in my local and I open the stackoverflow and try to get local value using APIs bind in stackoverflow web app

Answer (score 1):

CORS is a complex topic, I usually use [CORS middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) to handle it in Node.JS in Express server (maybe the code will be useful to solve this).

It's [goal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is to allow API on domain `api-domain` to list web applications that can use it, for example your application is on `webapp-domain` domain.

When application calls `fetch('http://api-domain/get-id/')` to another domain it is referred to as cross-origin call.

All browser do [CORS preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) call like this to check for allowance:

```
OPTIONS /get-id/
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: origin, x-requested-with
Origin: http://webapp-domain
```

(please note it's an OPTION request to the API, not GET)

And response should list `webapp-domain` as allowed (and specify which HTTP methods are allowed)

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://webapp-domain
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

After the successful preflight call like this the browser will continue with `fetch`, for example, it will send GET request to `http://api-domain/get-id/`

*P.S.*

One of the ways to skip CORS is to set HTTP proxy in `webapp-domain` which will call `api-domain` on server-side and is not limited by CORS. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141) answer for details.